# Quantum oscillator transition amplitude

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

I have a quick question regarding an equation in my textbook. It's about calculating the probability transition amplitude of a quantum oscillator.

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE EQUATION]

Why is this true? The difference between the first and the second row seems to be small. There is a **minus** sign before $\dfrac{i}{\hbar}$. In the top row there is a term with a **plus** sign and a term with a **minus** sign. Doesn't that mean that on the bottom row they should be **minus** and **plus** respectively. Why are they both positive?

I thought there is a mistake in the book but I found a similar derivation in other books, so I guess I am missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: They've used integration by parts to write the action as a quadratic form, this is extremely common in path integral formulation

Comment: Could you give me a little more details? Thanks!

Comment: Working on it so you can see

Comment: Alright, most appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262233/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral we want to simplify is the following

$\int_0^t dt'\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2(t') - \omega^2r^2(t')) $

The second part is fine and doesn't need any work, so we will work with the first term.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{m}{2}\int_0^t dt'\dot{r}^2(t') &=& \frac{m}{2}\int_0^t dt' \partial_{t'}r(t') \cdot \partial_{t'}r(t') \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Now we let $$\partial_tr \partial_tr = \partial_t (r \partial_t r) - r \partial^2_t r $$

This makes the above integral equal to

$$\frac{m}{2}\int_0^t dt' \partial_{t'}r(t') \cdot \partial_{t'}r(t') =
\left.r\partial_{t'} r\right|^t_0 -\frac{m}{2}\int_0^t dt'r \partial^2_{t'} r$$

Typically in path integral formulation, the endpoints of the first integral cause the evaluation to be zero as the path ends and begins exactly at the points (no variation). So we are left with

$$-\frac{m}{2}\int_0^t dt'r \partial^2_{t'} r$$

Combining this with your original integral yields

$$\int_0^t dt' \frac{m}{2}(-r\partial^2_{t'} r - \omega^2 r^2(t')) $$

We then pull out an r to the right and left, plus the negative sign to obtain

$$ -\int_0^t dt' \frac{m}{2}r(t')(\partial^2_{t'}  + \omega^2) r(t')$$

Comment: Its a good idea to commit this little trick to memory and understand it, its very often used in field theory and above

Comment: Thank you! That will be very useful to me in solving other problems in the future.

Comment: One last thing... As far as I understand, the final answer  $r(t')\partial_{t'}^2r(t')$ is the function $r(t')$, multiplied by its second derivative. That is how it is written in my book, too. However, the answer to the task I have to solve contains the first derivative squared... So it's different.

Comment: Id have to see the full question in the book

Comment: Alright, I'll post it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: PICTURE1]

[image: PICTURE2]

The notation is slightly different.

Comment: Might want to post to http://physics.stackexchange.com/ for more gory details on this problem